# Read nested array dynamicly in php

Tags: php, arrays

I need to read nested arrays without knowing how the array will look.

For example;

```
$data = array(
        'Data1_lvl1' => array(
                            'Data1_lvl2' => "value",
                            'Data2_lvl2' => array(
                                                'Data1_lvl3' => "value"
                                            )
                        ),
        'Data2_lvl1' => 'value'
    );
```

Needs to be formatted to strings like:

1. Data1_lvl1/Data1_lvl2/
2. Data1_lvl1/Data2_lvl2/Data1_lvl3/
3. Data2_lvl1/

But the array can be of any size with any number of nested arrays inside it.

Comment: You can use the built in `array_walk_recursive` function of PHP. refer  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data = array(
        'Data1_lvl1' => array(
                            'Data1_lvl2' => "value",
                            'Data2_lvl2' => array(
                                                'Data1_lvl3' => "value"
                                            )
                        ),
        'Data2_lvl1' => 'value'
    );


function printArray($array)
{
    foreach ($array as $key=>$value)
    {
       echo $key.'/';
       if (is_array($value))
       {
          printArray($value);           
       } else {    
        echo '<br>';
        }

    }

}


printArray($data);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to output only the name of array elements then this recursive function will do the trick.

**Your data:**

```
$data = array(
        'Data1_lvl1' => array(
                            'Data1_lvl2' => "value",
                            'Data2_lvl2' => array(
                                                'Data1_lvl3' => "value"
                                            )
                        ),
        'Data2_lvl1' => 'value'
    );
```

**Function:**

```
function array2str($array, $str) {
  foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    if (is_array($val) ) {
        $str .= $key . '/';
        array2str($val, $str);
    }
  }
  echo $str.'<br />';  
  return $str;
}

array2str($data);
```

As you can see the script does ECHO in itself with `<br />` to break the line when viewing results in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

One way would to walk recursively through array with function similar to this:

```
<?php
function f($d, $str = '') {
        foreach ($d as $key => $val) {
                if (is_array($val)) f($val, $str . '/' . $key); // If this element is array parse next level
                else print_r($str . '/' . $key . '/'); // Output current string or do what you need to do with it..
        }
}

$data = array(
        'Data1_lvl1' => array(
                            'Data1_lvl2' => "value",
                            'Data2_lvl2' => array(
                                                'Data1_lvl3' => "value"
                                            )
                        ),
        'Data2_lvl1' => 'value'
);

f($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

with that function:

```
<?php
function print_tree ($data, $prefix = '', &$index = 1) {
  foreach($data as $key => $datum) {
    echo $index++ . '. ' . ($new_prefix =  $prefix . $key . '/') . PHP_EOL;
    if (is_array($datum)) {
      print_tree ($datum, $new_prefix, $index);
    }
  }
}
```

I get

> 1. Data1_lvl1/
> 2. Data1_lvl1/Data1_lvl2/
> 3. Data1_lvl1/Data2_lvl2/
> 4. Data1_lvl1/Data2_lvl2/Data1_lvl3/
> 5. Data2_lvl1/